# closeOnContentClick does nothing - using Ajax gathering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, magnific-popup

So I have the Magnific Popup plugin setup where, when you click a link, the popup comes up. and I want this popup to contain all information pertaining to said link. Now, I finally got everything to set up correctly, and view right, but I can't get the closeOnContentClick to work. I read that this is set to false by default, and still when you click the content, it goes away. I manually set it to false, and still does the same thing. Does this have to do with the width of the panel that comes up? I have it set specifically set to 800px, and still messes up

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#player_table').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "serverside/handler.php"
            //"jQueryUI": true,
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $('.popup').magnificPopup({
            type: 'ajax',
            closeOnContentClick: false
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
            ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
                ui.panel.html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                    "");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The Javascript should be all that is needed to debug.. but if you need the html, I can supply.

This is the Ajax response.

```
    <div id="pop-form" class="white-popup">
    <center>
        <h2>You're currently viewing <? echo $values['username']; ?>'s Profile Analysis</h2>

        <? if ($result !="" ) { //NO ERRORS on load.. produce form ?>

        <!-- create page -->
        <div id="left">
            I'm Left
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            I'm Right
        </div>

        <? } else { //ERROR - needs to be noted echo $a1 . " - ERROR"; 
        }?>
    </center>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @LeoFarmer I added the Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay.

You need to ensure you are not returning html and body tags in your ajax response as this will cause the `closeOnContentClick: false` to stop working correctly. Your response should just be wrapped in `div` tags.

Comment: I am using a PHP response.. Would this affect it? The code is provided, without the main PHP functionality @leofarmer